# How to rewrite this program of words frequency counter in the text file in c?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, full-text-search

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070657/c-program-to-count-the-word-frequency-in-a-text-file) we see the program which computes how frequent each word of text file is present. After some small corrections it becomes to work perfectly for sufficiently small files. I wanted to use it for large text file, but get an error "Segmentation fault". The reason is that there is an initialization of array

```
 char p[1000][512],
```

which is so small for large text (if I understand correctly, it can save only 1000 words (which in general may coincide)). If I try to enlarge the dimension of p, I also get this error (there cannot be arrays larger than 2000*2000 on my computer).

Could the code above be modified in order for opening large text files? If yes, how to do that? Could You write the code which modifies it?

Comment: The only correct answer would be "Yes". Do you have a **specific** question within site-rules?

Comment: @Olaf : I've rewritten the question.

Comment: You seem to confuse this site with a "gimme teh codez" site. Sorry, wrong place. (Yes, I could rewrite the code).

Comment: Start fixing the indentation of your program.

Answer (score 2):

Consider allocating your array on head using `malloc`.

When you declare your array like char `char p[1000][512]`, it allocates 512 * 1000 (about 512 Kb) on stack. Stack size is insufficient for large files. When you allocate your memory using malloc, you ask operating system to give you some additional memory in heap.

So, instead of your code you should do like

```
typedef char * string_t;
string_t * stringsArray = malloc(sizeof(string_t) * NUM_STRINGS_TO_ALLOCATE);
for (size_t i = 0; i < STRINGS_COUNT; ++i)
   stringsArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * NUM_CHARS_PER_STRING);
```

don't forget to `free` allocated memory after using it, like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < STRINGS_COUNT; ++i)
   free(stringsArray[i]);
free(stringsArray);
```